# High voltage booster with continuous output?

Tags: voltage-regulator, high-voltage, boost, module

I need a module that can take a DC voltage of 2V - 12V continuously as its input and produce atleast 2KV DC continuously as its output. I've come across high voltage generator boost modules but they produce output in pulse (discontinuous.) What I want to know is do such modules exist that can continuously produce thousands of volts from low input voltage? If yes what are they usually called as?

I'm aware of high voltage bench power supplies that can continuously produce thousands of volts. But I don't want that. I just want a smaller device such as a module.

**Application:**

I want to use the module to power a parallel plates electrostatic device.

Comment: Digikey has many *DC to DC converters*.

Comment: Q1: What power / current output? | Q2: Knowing the application is liable to help greatly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Current output is not a requirement for my application. Only high voltage is a requirement. About the application, I've updated my answer and mentioned the application.

Comment: Current output *is* a requirement. Even electrostatics use current - it may be small (1µA or less) but you'll have zero volts with zero current.

Comment: @rdtsc Yes your are correct. A small current about 1µA - 100mA is enough for my application.

Comment: At 2kV DC 100mA is going to be a lot more expensive than 1µA

Comment: Site rules: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: I do not know whether you are aware, but the basic premise of a boost converter requires switching operation, so nothing you find will be perfectly smooth unless you search for a different method to boost the DC signal. However, faster switching will of course give you a smoother result.

Comment: 2kV·1µA=2mW. 2kV·100mA = 200W. That's a hell of a difference.

Comment: Can also consider AC - HV transformer - voltage multiplier stages. The DC coming out of that will still have ripple, but not a lot.  Add an LRC filter after it, voila.

Comment: The only thing close that I was able to find was 14-18Vin to 2000vout and 20mA output. So 40W. I don't know of any modules that output high voltage with that much current.